# OpenCV reshape function does not work properly

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using OpenCV reshape function in order to reshape Mat of 25 rows and 1 column (so we have 25 data values) into Mat of 5 rows and 5 columns.

```
data = mu.reshape(5, 5);
```

When I look at my data variable in debugger, it has 5 rows but 1 column. If I print data at row(0) and col(0) it outputs all five values. So basically each row at col(0) contains 5 values.

My desired result is to get 5 rows and 5 columns where on each (row,col) will be one value.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The first parameter to reshape is the number of channels. You're making a 5 channel matrix of 5 rows and 1 column. You want a 1 channel matrix with 5 rows and 5 columns. Hence `mu.reshape(1,5);` or even `mu.reshape(0,5);`. Read the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-reshape)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to have misinterpreted the meaning of arguments of the `reshape()` function.

According to the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-reshape) the signature is

```
Mat Mat::reshape(int cn, int rows=0) const
```

With the following meaning of the arguments:

- **cn** – New number of channels. If the parameter is 0, the number of channels remains the same.
- **rows** – New number of rows. If the parameter is 0, the number of rows remains the same.

Note that the number of columns is implicit -- it's calculated from the existing matrix properties and the two parameters.

According to this, the code

```
data = mu.reshape(5, 5);
```

creates a 5-channel matrix of 5 rows and 1 column.

In order to reshape you matrix to a single channel 5x5 matrix, you have to do the following:

```
data = mu.reshape(1, 5);
```

Alternately, since the input matrix is already single channel, you can also use

```
data = mu.reshape(0, 5);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This makes sense!